# What does it say on this masu?

Tags: calligraphy

[image: masu]

([original image](http://banraishop.com/nt/NT2052003.jpg))

I am relatively bad at reading handwritten Japanese. I know the first character is 木 and the last is 桧, but I am unsure of what the second is.

Answer (score 4):

The character is 「曽」.

[[木曽]{きそ}[桧]{ひのき}](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%9C%A8%E6%9B%BD%E6%AA%9C)